# HTML Buttons has different margin between placing on HTML and being created by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

I has problem when I place buttons in HTML directly, they display extra margin.
But when I create them with JavaScript code, they display without margin.

```js
const div = document.createElement("div");
   const doneBtn = document.createElement("button");
   doneBtn.innerText = "Done";
   const delBtn = document.createElement("button");
   delBtn.innerText = "Delete";
   div.append(doneBtn);
   div.append(delBtn);
   document.body.append(div);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Minimal Todo List</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <button>Done</button>
      <button>Delete</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the output consistently the same. (Setting "margin:0" won't work)

Comment: There's a line break and a bunch of spaces between the buttons in your HTML, this gets turned into a single space during rendering. Your JS code doesn't add any whitespace in between. I'd use flexbox CSS to position the buttons: https://jsfiddle.net/c1m7v9d8/ A quick fix is to put the buttons right after one another in your HTML.

Comment: Interesting sutuation: you choose one out of clean code and clear result

Comment: @ChrisG Making the parent node as flexbox is probably the cleanest solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace whitespaces in HTML or use proper CSS to remove the extra spaces. In JS, there are no extra spaces between buttons.

Comment: Thank you. And for anybody that want a quick solution, you can set the parent node of buttons as flexbox.